# how to implement facebook in my application for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have complete code for implemention for facebook in my application But the problem arises as follow :

Firstly whenever i import FBConnect\FBConnect.h     the error will show that it doesn't "NO such file or direectory"

secondly due to this error i have 182 error in my application..

Thanks

Comment: Sharma, I have faced the same problem and rectified it. See Matthew Flaschen answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find "Header Search Paths" in build settings. Enter full path of the facebook sdk src folder(upto the folder-facebook-iphone-sdk/src) there.

This is assuming you have copied the reference of the FBConnect folder in your project and  not the files themselves.

I tried by copying the files directly, but couldn't do so. Following the facebook developer wiki word by word would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the compiler where to find the header files; in XCode, this is called "Header Search Path".  You will also have linker errors later if the libraries aren't accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Take care to see that your file name is correct..if so then check it out that that the file is present in the correct directory..