# Facebook Connect in Iphone header include path

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am trying to compile facebook library for my iphone application. But I am getting this error.

error: FBConnect/FBConnect.h: No such file or directory

I have added the location of the folder in header search paths and yet it is not compiling.

> This is the path that I have added-
>   /Users/nishant/Downloads/facebook-facebook-iphone-sdk-1059eb6/src.

I even tried the copy files to destination folder option, but that also did not work.

I know this is a very simple step, but I am getting frustrated, because I have tried this like 20-30 times.

Any help.

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012212/how-to-implement-facebook-in-my-application-for-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a *User Header Search Path* between the Build settings for your target. Set it to the root directory of the Facebook library code and it should build fine. (I have spent a while with the setting myself.)

Comment: Hi,

I think I have got the issue. Can you please check this link-http://img293.imageshack.us/img293/3855/screent.png.

I have uploaded the screenshot. The .h files are not being added to the target and that is causing the errors.

Comment: This is a helpful link for this issue.

http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=37182

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file is added to you current target - just expand 'Compile Sources' section in your target and see if the file is there.

Answer (score 0):

I too tried this for some time and finally imported the below line

## import "FBConnect.h"

instead of #import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h"

voila! it worked like a charm.